# Why are very thick soap bubbles colorless?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, optical-materials

Is it simply because the wavelength where constructive interference occurs gets to be too long?

Answer (score 2):

For thick films, rather than fitting 1 wavelength between surfaces. You may be able to fit many wavelengths of a particular color in the film thickness.

This would allow interference to occur the same as with thin bubbles at a given color, however, other colors are also more likely to have constructive interference. -> N * lambda

You might fit 5 red wavelengths, 7 green wavelengths, and 10 blue wavelengths precisely in the film thickness, and so all of these colors would have constructive interference. When you view something with all colors (red/green/blue) it looks the same as usual.

(the counts of wavelengths above are completely made up)

Rather than a single peak on the frequency spectrum at a specific colour, you will get many peaks across the color spectrum.